# How to make this petal shape a mesh?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

[image]

I am trying to make the petals in this image I made in illustrator in Blender but making it into a mesh that I can solidify so it looks like a 3d ring of petals that come out. How do I make this shape in Blender by itself? 
whenever I import it as a svg just hte flower poath it creaste a hollow design. I am clearly very new to all this would like some help please!

Answer (score 0):

Fill those petals in illustrator and after you fill that in illustrator application you will be able to fill that